# How to store the stacktrace in the database on Error with Microsoft Logging Application Block

Tags: logging, enterprise-library-5, logging-application-block

Hi I have a database trace listener and I would like to log the stack trace on the database when I get an error. I can add the stack trace to the message pretty easily but I would prefer to add it to another column in the database table. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a sample solution called Custom Database Trace Listener Sample at [Enterprise Library Sample Projects](https://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sample%20Projects).

The basic steps are to create a custom LogEntry class with a custom property.  An additional column is added to the [Log] table and the out of the box stored procedure is modified to accept a new parameter. Then a custom Trace Listener passes the custom property data to the stored procedure where it is inserted into the database.